# Legal transcript

Tags: american-english

How would you write the following sentences in legal transcripts:

> Mr. Doe, I understand your statement, but the question is, did you drink tea for breakfast?

Do you add a comma after "the question is/was"?

Comment: I'd expect that anyone who was writing legal transcripts, would have a set of style guidelines to follow covering formatting and punctuation.

Comment: I'm on my way to become certified but I've been writing transcripts in French and pure English. I see those type of sentences a lot in examination for discoveries.

Comment: Good answer from Xanne, but why don't you ask at Law.SE to get their take?  By the way, I've seen very sloppy professional transcripts.  Perhaps you could ask a mentor if the following is true (as is my guess): that getting the words right, and the utterance accurate and readable, is more important than punctuation decisions that are style questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the comma.

One of the transcription services in the U.S. quotes the Purdue on-line writing guide [here](https://www.gmrtranscription.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/use-of-comma-in-transcription.pdf) on the use of the comma, concluding with this:

> Use commas whenever necessary to prevent possible confusion or misreading.

The use of the comma to indicate a pause is also mentioned, as well as the usual rules. But avoiding confusion and misreading would be the top priority in a legal transcript.

Ellipses are not used to indicate pauses, even longer ones, because they normally indicate that something’s been left out, which would not be appropriate in a transcript.